# Nested for loop taking much time in Python (Optimization)

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, optimization

I have a python code with nested for loop and it is taking too much time, consider having a dictionary like `dict = {'110': ('jade'), '2': ('amber'), '111' : ('harry')}`

and here is my code-

```
all_keys = dict.keys()
for number in all_keys:
    for more_number in all_keys:
        if SequenceMatcher(None, number, more_number).ratio() > 0.5:
            dict[number] = dict[number].union(dict[more_number])
```

**Output:-**

```
dict = {'110' : ('jade', 'harry'), '2' : ('amber')}
```

what this code is doing is checking if the keys have a matching probability of more than 0.5 and if so it is adding both the keys in a set and storing it. For more data, it is taking so much time for obvious reasons. Is there any way to optimise?

Comment: The code you posted does not work. (Strings don't have `.union`)

Comment: @AKX its a dict of tuples of strings ?

Comment: dont use `dict` as varaible name...

Comment: @PatrickArtner No, it's not. `('jade')` is a string in parens, `('jade',)` is a 1-member tuple. Besides, tuples don't have `union` either. (Sets do.)

Comment: @AKX Thanks, my bad

Comment: Yeah sorry forgot to mention that values are sets, my bad. @AKX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, your code is allocating an instance of `SequenceMatcher` in each iteration of the iner loop, `O(N^2)` in total.

Considering all that's taken out of it is a single value it should be possible to make it stateless and use a single pre-allocated instance.

Additionally, instead of iterating over keys and paying unnecessary lookup cost in the innermost loop (saving `O(N^2)` lookups), you could just iterate with `for k,v in d.items():`.

And lastly, I am almost sure (need to see the code of the `SequenceMatcher` to be sure) it is possible to do what you need to do better than in `O(N^2)` (at least as `O(N log(N))`).

Comment: Okay that was helpful bobah, I changed the inner loop but it is not helping much.

Comment: @l0n3_w01f - how does the latest code look like and what's inside the `SequenceMatcher`?

Comment: I changed the inner loop from iterating to the list to `for k,v in d.items():` which is also a list. The `SequenceMatcher` is a module used for comparing two strings, I think it iterates over each character in string to find matching probability.